# No signature of method: org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest.srcFile()

Tags: java, android-studio, gradlew

In Android studio, I just want to define a custom project structure for android project(follow this, http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure), but when run:
    ./gradlew tasks
I got the error: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'greendao-example'.

> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest.srcFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [AndroidManifest.xml]

The build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
}

   dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
   }

}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'java'

  repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    testBuildType = "debug"

    defaultConfig {
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "0.1"
    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 17


    compileSdkVersion = 17
    buildConfig "private final static boolean DEFAULT = true;", \
                "private final static String FOO = \"foo\";"
    }

    buildTypes {
    debug {
        packageNameSuffix = ".debug"

        buildConfig "private final static boolean DEBUG2 = false;"
    }
    }

    aaptOptions {
    noCompress "txt"
    }
    sourceSets {          
     manifest.srcFile  'AndroidManifest.xml'

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the manifest to the main sourceSet.

```
sourceSets {
    main {          
        manifest.srcFile  'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

See the migrated example in the gradle samples from Google:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-samples-0.5.zip